# Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape' while trying to covert datetime in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Consider a I have a column called 'test' of a dataframe. The column elements are like this:

```
201604
201605
```

I want to make the each column elements of the dataframe as 2016-04-01. Based on this I have written a code which is working fine in spyder but when I am trying to apply it to Jupyter Notebook it is showing
some error **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'**

My code is:

```
df['test'] = pd.to_datetime(df['test'].apply(lambda x: x[:4])+"-"+df['test'].apply(lambda x: x[-2:]))
```

Initially I have used the following code

```
df['test'] = pd.to_datetime(df['test'].apply(lambda x: str(x[:4]))+"-"+df['test'].apply(lambda x: 
                                                                str(x[-2:]))+"-01",format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

In both cases it is showing error. Kindly help so that I can use it in Jupyter Notebook.

Note that dtypes is object for 'test'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use `format` param while converting the `str to datetime`

**Input**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'test':['201604', '201605']
})
df
```

**Input df**

```
test
0   201604
1   201605
```

**Code**

```
df.test = pd.to_datetime(df.test, format='%Y%m')
df
```

**Output**

```
    test
0   2016-04-01
1   2016-05-01
```